# Compare two files,delete a line if matches found

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I want to compare two files.

If values from `file2` are matching with the first two columns of `file1` need to delete the whole line from `file1` and print the result into `output` as shown below.

Below contains values of `file1`:

```
1,aplle,melle,cyborg
2,bplle,less,vgm
3,minipl,vicy,bgm
4,tag,mob,calic
6,Centurion,sa,hh
```

Below contains values of `file2`

```
2,bplle
4,tag
5,Centurion
```

And `output` must contains below:

```
1,aplle,melle,cyborg
3,minipl,vicy,bgm
6,Centurion,sa,hh
```

Is it possible to achieve this `awk` ?

Comment: Based on [this description of awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), yes, I'd say it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next} !(($1,$2) in a)' file2 file1
1,aplle,melle,cyborg
3,minipl,vicy,bgm
6,Centurion,sa,hh
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also work: `grep -Fwvf file2 file1`

> -F
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings,
>
> -w
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole words.
>
> -v
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
>
> -f FILE
> Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.